# Getting an error could not find function in a for loop

Tags: r

I'm running the following code:

```
dat1 <- returns

for (j in 1:12) set(dat1, j = j, value = wind(dat1[[j]]))
```

And getting the following error message:

```
Error in wind(dat1[[j]]) : could not find function "wind"
```

My search for a solution mainly involves packages that aren't properly installed. I'm not 100% sure but I think it isn't related to that.

Best

Answer (score 0):

To check if the `function` is really loaded into the namespace you have to try to
print the function:

```
print(wind)
Error in print(wind) : object 'wind' not found
```

You have to look if the package is correctly loaded

```
library("foo")
```

Check package dependency in case of error.

Answer (score 0):

I use the `findFn`-function in sos-package to search for function names. Unfortunately dataset names also appear in the same column:

```
install.packages("sos")
library(sos)
findFn("wind")
```

There is a wind function (or dataset name) in packages: gstat, ismev,  NPCirc, BAMBI,  ggmap, gcookbook, CircOutlier, plotly, and circular.